# Reinstalled Conda Not Recognized and Cannot launch Anaconda Navigator

Tags: anaconda, environment-variables, conda

I had to uninstall/reinstall Anaconda (20232.03-1 64bit) on Windows 10. I now cannot get the Anaconda Prompt to recognize any conda statements nor can I launch the Anaconda Navigator.

If I go into the Anaconda Prompt I see the following:

> PS C:\Users\MyName

I am not sure what "PS" means (Powershell?).  And it is preceded by this statement:

> Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\python.exe
> "C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" shell.powershell
> activate "C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3"' Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind
> argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string. At
> C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1:76 char:36
>
> - ```
>       Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;
>   ```
> - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Invo
>   keExpressionCommand

If I go into the CMD prompt and type "Where conda:

> C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe

To fix this I decided to Win+R and Run sysdm.cpl. Then went into System Properties and chose Advanced, and clicked on Environment Variables. Then in the User Variable for MyName I clicked on Path and then Edit and I added the following 2x paths:

> C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\Scripts

> C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3

But none of this is working. Can anyone make a suggestion on next steps. Thank-you in advance.

Comment: The issue appears to reside in the psm1 file on line 76, character 36 as per the error message. This is inside a function called Enter-Conda Environment. I think it is the statement below that starts with Invoke-Expression. But I don't understand what portion of that is considered an "empty string" to generate the error. The 36th character is the "C" in "$activateCommand"


`Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;`